# Não consigo fazer um merge na branch Develop

Tags: git

Saudações amigos(as).

Eu tenho dois Branchs 'main' e 'develop'. Tenho alterações no 'develop', já fiz o commit e tudo mais, mas quando vou para a branch 'main' e tendo dar um 'merge' na 'develop', ele me diz que:

```
Already up to date.
```

Como posso resolver?

---

Ressaltando que o conteúdo de Main está desatualizado com relação ao Develop, então o que eu preciso fazer é "jogar" tudo que tenho em Develop dentro do Main

Answer (score 1):

O "sentido" do teu merge está ao contrário... Você tem que pegar as modificações que estão na `Develop` e passar para a `master`. Como fazer isso? assim:

Vamos assumir que você está na branch `Develop` e já fez o `commit`

1. mudar para a branch master
   `git checkout master`
2. fazer o merge da `Develop` para `master`
   `git merge Develop`

Answer (score 0):

O merge de modificações deve ser realizado no seguinte sentido: `desenvolvimento -> main` e não `main -> desenvolvimento`, já que a branch que contém as modificações é a de desenvolvimento.

Esta por sua vez é derivada da branch main, por este motivo que ao realizar o merge `main -> desenvolvimento` mostra que a branch `desenvolvimento` já está atualizada, pois o conteúdo de `main` já existe em `desenvolvimento`.

Você poderia mostrar a saída do comandos `git checkout main; git log` e `git checkout develop; git log` sinalizando quais são os commits e em qual branch eles estão?

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).